# GROUP BY columns of different no of rows in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a problem . I am writing a script that is following

```
SELECT distinct(customer_id),
(CASE WHEN (LoanCycleAgainstPartner = 1 and dpd > 0) THEN 'not paid in time' ELSE 'paid in time' END) as 'First Loan Payment',
(CASE WHEN (LoanCycleAgainstPartner = 2 and dpd > 0) THEN 'not paid in time' ELSE 'paid in time' END) as 'Second Loan  Payment',
(CASE WHEN (LoanCycleAgainstPartner = 3 and dpd > 0) THEN 'not paid in time' ELSE 'paid in time' END) as 'Third Loan Payment'
FROM database1.`2022.12.29_loan_details` 
WHERE partnername = 'Uber B.V.'
GROUP BY customer_id ;
```

I have attached the photo of output[Output of my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scUAQ.png)
The problems is that in 3rd and 4th column. Same value is repeating

The problem is Three columns that I want to show in output have different no of rows and I want to group By against "customer_id". 3rd and 4th column are showing only one value across the column.
How I group by columns of different no of rows

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to show some sample rows from your table and the result set you require from those rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aggregating the various `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT
    customer_id,
    CASE WHEN SUM(LoanCycleAgainstPartner = 1 AND dpd > 0) > 0
         THEN 'not paid in time' ELSE 'paid in time' END AS `First Loan Payment`,
    CASE WHEN SUM(LoanCycleAgainstPartner = 2 AND dpd > 0) > 0
         THEN 'not paid in time' ELSE 'paid in time' END AS `Second Loan Payment`,
    CASE WHEN SUM(LoanCycleAgainstPartner = 3 AND dpd > 0) > 0
         THEN 'not paid in time' ELSE 'paid in time' END AS `Third Loan Payment`
FROM database1.`2022.12.29_loan_details` 
WHERE partnername = 'Uber B.V.'
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Comment: Can you tell me on more thing? . In my table few customers have taken loan only once. I don'twant to show them in 3rd and 4th columns .How will I do it?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahKhan Rows within a query result all must have the same number of columns. No way around. What you *could* do is filling `null`s into the surplus columns to indicate that there's no result for.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why you add SUM in case statement and why it should be greater than 0 -@Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahKhan The _boolean_ expression inside `SUM(...)` will logically return 0 or 1 if false or true, respectively.  So the `SUM(...)` expression then _counts_ the number of times the expression is true.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for you response. I want to know why my answer is not correct when I not use the sum() inside WHEN. Please answer. I want to learn logic behind using sum statement.. Please answer

Comment: I have already answered your question in my previous comment.